# How to fix my mongoose query from randomly failing to find a document that hasn't changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My mongoose(5.5.15) query is sometimes able to "findById" the document and "select" the sub-document based on the conditional query provided. However, just one second later (or whatever amount of time) the exact same request fails to return anything back. Nothing is changing on the MongoDb document so it has to be something I am doing wrong.

I have already used the console.log(nextDeliveryDate) to get the date object output when the query seemingly fails and the output of the log seems to be the same (except for the time difference from the previous of course). So the error appears to be completely random and uncontrolled.

```
const today = new Date();
let nextDeliveryDate = new Date();
nextDeliveryDate.setHours(0);
nextDeliveryDate.setMinutes(0);
nextDeliveryDate.setSeconds(0);
if (today.getDay() < 2) {
  nextDeliveryDate.setDate(today.getDate() + (2 - today.getDay()));
} else {
  nextDeliveryDate.setDate(today.getDate() + (7 - today.getDay()));
}

const result = await Kitchen.findById(req.query.kitchen).select({
  deliveries: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      delivery_date: {
        $gte: nextDeliveryDate
      }
    }
  }
}).exec();

// SCHEMA from a different file
const kitchenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
_created: Date,
_lastModified: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
location: {
    street: String,
    unit: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zipcode: Number,
    latitude: Number,
    longitude: Number
},
routes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Routes'
}],
manager: {
    type: String
},
employees: [{
    type: String
}],
deliveries: [{
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    _created: Date,
    weekday: Number,
    delivery_date: Date,
    routes: [{...}],
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'preparing'
    }
}]
});
```

So sometimes I get the perfect result that I am expecting (the correct delivery object from the array) and sometimes it just doesn't find anything. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any try/catch block which may hide other possible reasons (network error for example)?

Comment: Yes it's inside of a try/catch block but its not firing. The query returns result.deliveries[0] which contains the object I want... or result.deliveries[0] is null just a simple moment later when I retry the same function  again.

Comment: If you are not [hiding error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding) then you may writing to db while running your query with results the same as described [here](https://blog.meteor.com/mongodb-queries-dont-always-return-all-matching-documents-654b6594a827).